# MVC checkbox Get

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, filter

I am trying to implement a search panel with several checkbox to filter a table data, but i have a problem. I cant retain value of input checked after submit.

How can I solve?

My model :

```
public class OrdineView
{
    public int anno { get; set; }
    public Int32 nrOrdine { get; set; }
    public string centro { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime? data { get; set; }
    public String codice { get; set; }
    public String ragsoc { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    public Nullable<double> importo;
}
```

I have a Search model:

```
public class OrdiniSearchModel
{
    public  int? anno {get;set;}
    public String[] Distinzione {get;set;}
}

public class OrdiniBusinessLogic
{
    private NORTHWNDEntities1 db;
    public OrdiniBusinessLogic()
    {
        db = new NORTHWNDEntities1();
    }

    public IQueryable<OrdineView> GetOrdini(OrdiniSearchModel ordiniSearch)
    {
        var queryOrdineView = (from ordine in db.ORDINI
                               join cliente in db.CLIENTI on ordine.Codcli equals cliente.Codana
                               select new OrdineView
                               {
                                   anno = ordine.Anno,
                                   nrOrdine = ordine.Numord,
                                   centro = ordine.Codcen,
                                   data = ordine.Datord,
                                   codice = ordine.Codcli,
                                   ragsoc = cliente.Ragso1,
                                   importo = ordine.Totord
                               }).ToList().AsQueryable();

        var model = queryOrdineView;
        if (ordiniSearch.anno != null)
        {
            model = model.Where(o => o.anno == ordiniSearch.anno);
        }
        if (ordiniSearch.Distinzione != null && ordiniSearch.distinzione.Count() > 0)
        {
            List<string> distinzioniSelezionate = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in ordiniSearch.Distinzione)
            {
                distinzioniSelezionate.Add(item);
            }
            model = model.Where(o => distinzioniSelezionate.Contains(o.distinzione));

        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(OrdiniSearchModel searchModel, int? pageNumber )
{
    ViewBag.Anno = db.ORDINI.Select(o => new { o.Anno }).Distinct().OrderByDescending(o => o.Anno).Select(o => o.Anno);  
    var searchLogic = new OrdiniBusinessLogic();
    var model = searchLogic.GetOrdini(searchModel);
    return View(model.OrderBy(i => i.codice).ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 10));           
}
```

In my view I have

```
<input name="Distinzione"  type="checkbox"  value="001">001
<input name="Distinzione"  type="checkbox"  value="002">002
```

...and so on

After submit I get data correctly but lose checked state.

Comment: Because you manually generating the html for your checkboxes which will not give you model binding.

Comment: Please could you show how to solve? I used also html.Checkbox but nothing change. how do you solve this kind of problem...i am a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Based on the comments, I updated the view and adde more code.

If you mean that the checkboxes don't stay checked after the page is refreshed. It's because you don't tell them which should be checked. There is one possible solution for you. Create a simple helper method right in the view where you need the checkboxes. This method just checks the array of values and if it finds the value there, it will render a checkbox with checked state.

*View.cshtml*

```
@model OrdinePagedList

@MyCheckbox("001")
@MyCheckbox("002")

@helper MyCheckbox(string value) 
{
    if (Model.Distinzione.Contains(value))
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="Distinzione" value="@value" checked="checked"/>
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="Distinzione" value="@value" />
    }

    @value
}
```

I suggest to create a new view model class:

```
public class OrdinePagedList
{
    public IEnumerable<OrdiniView> Pages { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Distinzione { get; set;
}
```

And update either your business logic so that it returns this new class

```
// from
public IQueryable<OrdineView> GetOrdini(OrdiniSearchModel ordiniSearch)
// to
public OrdinePagedList GetOrdini(OrdiniSearchModel ordiniSearch)
```

or update the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(OrdiniSearchModel searchModel, int? pageNumber )
{
    ViewBag.Anno = db.ORDINI.Select(o => new { o.Anno }).Distinct().OrderByDescending(o => o.Anno).Select(o => o.Anno);  
    var searchLogic = new OrdiniBusinessLogic();
    var pages = searchLogic.GetOrdini(searchModel);

    OrdinePagedList model = new OrdiniPagedList {
        Pages = pages.OrderBy(i => i.codice).ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 10),
        Distinzione = searchModel.Distinzione
    }

    return View(model);           
}
```

or if you don't want (or can't) create the new view model (but I strongly recommend to do so). You can use ViewBag to pass the additinal collection of checked values:

```
public ActionResult Index(OrdiniSearchModel searchModel, int? pageNumber)
{
    ViewBag.Distinzione = searchModel.Distinzione;
    // original code
}
```

and then you'll just have to update the helper method. For the sake of simplicity I don't check if the ViewBag.Distinzione exists. But you should.

```
@helper MyCheckbox(string value) 
{
    if (ViewBag.Distinzione.Contains(value))
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="Distinzione" value="@value" checked="checked"/>
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="Distinzione" value="@value" />
    }

    @value
}
```

In short. You need to make sure that the data (collection of checked values), you get in controller, are being sent back to the view.

Comment: tks a lot for answer...but my view has a model as @model IPagedList<Project.ViewModels.OrdineView>. How can i solve? In any case tks

Comment: I forgot... yes problem is lose checked state

Comment: Now i cant try your suggest but you open my mind...im sure it will work. Tks again. In any issue ill tell you. Sorry for english.

Comment: I try to edit the ActionResult in order to get selected "Distinzione"  and in some way with helper works. But im interested in your solution with new class. I tried to implement the view but i cant iterate the field of Pages. how with @model OrdinePageList ? I also tried with IEnumerable<OrdinePageList> !

Comment: I get OrdinePagedList' does not contain a definition for 'Anno' and no extension method 'Anno' accepting a first argument of type 'OrdinePagedList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: ok now works...now I understand what you suggest: extend viewmodel with field that represent a filter in the view! Right ? In any case tks a lot

Comment: Exactly. That's what view models are for - all kind of informations you need for a particular view, just include it in the view model class. And it also includes field/input data if you want to keep their values/states after refresh. I'm glad it worked for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> distinzioniSelezionate = new List<string>();
            if (searchModel.distinzione != null && searchModel.distinzione.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in searchModel.distinzione)
                {
                    distinzioniSelezionate.Add(item);
                }
            }
            OrdinePagedList model = new OrdinePagedList
            {
                Pages = pages.OrderBy(i => i.Codice).ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 10),
                Distinzione = distinzioniSelezionate
            };
```

I had to modify the ActionResult because Distinzione is not empty